# Repeating a code execution

Tags: c#

I am trying to repeat a code execution after predefined time passes and i don't want to mess up things by using threads. Is the below code a good practice?

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch(); // sw constructor
EXIT:
    // Here I have my code
    sw.Start();
    while (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < 100000)
    {
        // do nothing, just wait
    }

    System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play(); // for test
    sw.Stop();
    goto EXIT;
```

Comment: Good example of bad practices ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a timer what Oded suggested:

```
public partial class TestTimerClass : Form
{
    Timer timer1 = new Timer(); // Make the timer available for this class.
    public TestTimerClass()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Tick += timer1_Tick; // Assign the tick event
        timer1.Interval = 1000; // Set the interval of the timer in ms (1000 ms = 1 sec)
        timer1.Start(); // Start the timer
    }

    void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
        timer1.Stop(); //  Stop the timer (remove this if you want to loop the timer)
    }
}
```

EDIT: Just want to show you how to make an easy timer if you don't know how to :)

Answer (score 4):

Use a *timer* instead of labels and `StopWatch`. You are doing busy waiting, tying up the CPU in that tight loop.

You start a timer, giving it an interval to fire on (100000 milliseconds), then run your code in the event handler for the `Tick` event.

See [Comparing the Timer Classes in the .NET Framework Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx) in MSDN magazine.